# How to download multiple PDFs with curl in Terminal.app

Tags: curl, terminal

In terminal.app I entered this line

`curl -o http://print.nap.edu/pdf/0309065577/pdf_image/[1-319].pdf`

And it in Terminal it says:

`curl: no URL specified!`

How is this possible? I'm just trying to download a bunch of successively numbered PDF files from a web server. If I leave off the `-o` it just downloads a bunch of gibberish into the Terminal window but not as a file. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
curl -o file_#1.pdf 'http://foo.bar/abc/[1-319].pdf'
```

note two things: (1) the placeholder #1 in the (2) output file name

Comment: I figured it out. I just put `-O` as a capital letter instead of `-o` as a small letter and it worked.

Comment: also works with padded numbers! (e.g. `[001-319]` instead of `[1-319]`)